# Leaderboard to return ranking in addition to score

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-2

I’ve got a top 100 leaderboard set up in my game using php mysql and it's working well. However, what I would also like is to show the player their position even if they haven’t got a high enough score to be in the top 100.

So my table has `id`, `user`, `score` and the php is as follows:

```
$getscore = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $nameTable order by userscore desc LIMIT 0 , 100 ");

if (!$getscore || mysql_num_rows($getscore)==0) {
    $msg = mysql_error();
    $string .= '&kode=Data Failed&';
} else {
    $string .= '&nr='.mysql_num_rows ($getscore);
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($getscore)) {
        while (list ($key, $val) = each ($row)) {
            $string .= '&' . $key . $i . '=' . stripslashes($val) ;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    $string .='&';
}
```

And the as2 script is:

```
myData.onLoad = function(success)
{
    if (success)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < myData.nr; i++)
        {
            scroll.spContentHolder["n" + i].text = myData["username" + i];
            scroll.spContentHolder["s" + i].text =  myData["userscore" + i];
        }
    }
```

So how would I go about returning a player's rank and score to display at the top of my leaderboard?  I've read about indexing the score in MySQL but not sure how to relate that back to the php and as2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're looking for the SQL query to do this or the PHP code or both. Here's the SQL query that you're looking for, since I don't know anything about actionscript.

Assuming that you have (or can get) the username or ID into a variable (I'm going to assume you have ID)

```
SELECT username, score FROM $tablename WHERE id=$id;
```

Comment: I would assume it would be both since the as2 calls a php file which accesses the MySQL database. And yes the first column in MySQL is id.

Answer (score 0):

Querying the row of the player already gives you the score. However, you need to add a sub-query to get the rank as in:

```
SELECT  t0.*,
    (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    $tablename t1
        WHERE   t1.score >= t0.score
    ) AS rank
FROM    $tablename t0
WHERE   $id = '$id';
```

In PHP, the rank will then be available under the 'rank' key in the result set. You will then have to parse an additional key-value pair in your AS2 code for the rank. There's a tutorial on tutsplus.com where the entire system is described: [Self-Hosted PHP/SQL Leaderboard](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-code-a-self-hosted-phpsql-leaderboard-for-your-game--gamedev-11627)